# How to make a tableview fill all the available space?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is my first swift application, so apologize if it's very basic. I was unable to find it...

[image]

In my view, I've a Navigation on top (Navigation Controller) and It's using a TabBar Controller. I'd like to make the TableView fill the whole empty space no matter the size of the device nor orientation.

I set the property Content Mode to many different options, including Aspect Fill, but all the options can't cause any effect.

Any clue about it ?

Comment: Do you use AutoLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your tableview completely fill the screen and then set the constraints to be in 0 margin from all sides, like in the image [image: constraints]

Answer (score 0):

use constraints for display full table view on empty space.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ1tv.png)

Click on pin icon from bottom side of Xcode.
Select all for four(up,down,left,right) constraints and set 0 value for all.
after then click on add constraints button and refresh frame(click on right side button of Pin button and select Update Frame).